# Как удалить таблицу из базы данных, используя Pony ORM и Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

pony orm, база posgresql , необходимо удалить таблицу после окончания сценария
пробовал методы delete и drop table, ошибка всегда одна

pony.orm.core.TransactionError: @db_session-decorated drop_table() function with `ddl` option cannot be called inside of another db_session

пробовал декорировать, но все равно такая же ошибка.

изначально я записал текст в таблицу. отправил текст и после отправки мне его надо удалить
пишу текст таким образом

```
Routes(number_choice=number_choice, flight_time=flight_time, city_from=city_from, city_to=city_to,
                       flight_board=flight_board, flight_date=flight_date)
            select = db.select('number_choice,flight_time,city_from,city_to,flight_board,flight_date FROM Routes')
            text_to_send = ' '.join(select[0]) + '\n' + ' '.join(select[1]) + '\n' + ' '.join(
                select[2]) + '\n' + ' '.join(
                select[3]) + '\n' + ' '.join(select[4]) + '\n'
            self.send_text(text_to_send=text_to_send, user_id=user_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может кому пригодится
Routes.select(lambda p: p.id > 0 ).delete(bulk=True)